# PHP File Upload Error - Undefined Index , Encytype used, File Permissions are right

Tags: php, file, upload

I've been trying to solve why my file is not getting uploaded. I thought it was my school's permission causing error so I am running it over wampserver but I am still getting an undefined error and 'file was not uploaded'. I tried several echos, the file name is right, the directory is right and being create but the file will not upload to the directory. When I put it manually in the directory it uploads fine to my database so I have no idea what's wrong.

Outside of my header/body

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
require_once('config.php');
    $link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die ('Your DB connection is misconfigured. Enter the correct values and try again.');
    //$query = mysqli_query(
?>
```

And here's the file upload:

```
<?php include 'navigation.php';?>

    <h1> Welcome, <?php 
    echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?> !</h1>


<!-- upload file script-->      
<?php

    if(!file_exists ("uploads/".$_SESSION['login_user'])){ //making the user directory
        mkdir("uploads/".$_SESSION['login_user'], 0777, true);      
    }

    $img_target_dir = "uploads/".$_SESSION['login_user']; //puts stuff in uploads
    $target_file2 = $img_target_dir. basename($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]); //img file
    echo $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



    // Allow certain file formats for images (png)
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($imageFileType == "png") {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"]);
            echo $img_target_dir . "/" . $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
            if($check != false) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"], $img_target_dir . "/" . $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"])) {
                    //chmod("uploads/img/lab2_upload.png",0777);
                    //echo "Image file size: ";
                    //echo filesize("uploads/img/lab2_upload.png") . "<br>";
                    //echo '<img src= "uploads/img/lab2_upload.png" height="300" width="300">';
                }
                else {
                    echo "file was not uploaded";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "error uploading image";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "File not png<br>";
        }

    }

?>

    <!-- FORM FOR PHP UPLOAD -->        
    <section class="bg-primary" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">

                <!-- Upload image-->    
                    <h2> Image Upload </h2>
                    <h4> Ensure that the file upload is a PNG file!</h4>


                    <form action="profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <div><h2>Upload a PNG file: </h2>
                        <input class="btn btn-default btn-xl wow tada" id="imgfile" type="file" name="imgfile" value="imgfile">
                            <br>
                            <input class="btn btn-default btn-xl wow tada" id="Upload" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And a screenie: http://puu.sh/o7x1c/e3ee43d124.jpg

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]`,...)` => `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"]`,...)`

Comment: Wow, that actually worked! Thanks so much, what a silly mistake.

Comment: Your content validation is not providing as much protection as it should. There's a significant risk someone could use this to inject code into the server.

Comment: Its also a good idea to start all file upload processing by checking the `$_FILES['imgfile']['error']` code. Its all pretty well described in of all the odd places [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)